# Demon background API to query graphAPI without login/consent page

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to read calendar data of the Azure active directory users and fetch all the meeting at a particular time.

I want to do this inside .NET core WebAPI. But i don't want to have any login page neither I want to pop up consent page to the user.

I want all of this to happen in the background, but I can provide the user credential in the configuration file.

Is this possible provided Graph API supports only OAuth?

Any leads/samples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Recommended way to work with Daemon applications will be to use Client Credentials flow and utilize application permissions (not delegated).. You will NOT need to go through login page in this case. Consent would probably be required for app permissions but that can be one time thing and not for end user but by an admin and possibly through Azure portal itself.. There is a legacy way to use username/password, but not recommended and opens up security risks too so I'll skip it.. BTW you've tagged azure-ad-graph-api.. but microsoft-graph api might be more relevant for most cases..

Comment: Here's a link that explains more details about Client Credentials Grant Flow.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: Client credentials grant flow, as Rohit said :)

Answer (score 1):

As everybody recommended, you want to use Client Credentials for a daemon application. For details see:

- https://aka.ms/msal-net-client-credentials
- in particular the following samples [Daemon applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#daemon-applications)